# urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

The code is working fine on localhost but having an issue when deployed over Azure Linux system:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote

url = (f"https://www.wikipedia.org/")
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

panel_data = soup.find('div')

print(panel_data)
```

Over Azure Linux system I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/flask-doker/app.py", line 41, in scrap
    content = scrappy()
  File "/flask-doker/scrapper.py", line 10, in scrappy
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)>
```

Expecting it to work on Azure Linux as good as it works locally

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], both for client and server.

Comment: The code scraps web data and give text output when run on localhost, but produces the provided error over Azure Linux system.

Comment: The code you provided declares a function and then exits. It doesn't do anything, effectively. I'm not going to guess what else you are doing. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] in case you haven't yet.

Comment: hi @UlrichEckhardt, I've edited the question for easy replication, please check now